# Unable to send variable from views to html python

Tags: python, django

Am Unable to sent the temp_k variable from my views to index.html. I have made a request from weather API and trying to pass it to my html.
    Please suggest how we are supposed to send the variable from views to template.

**`views.py`**

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
   my_dict = {'insert_me': "From andu.py"}
   return render(request, 'mywebapp/index.html', context=my_dict)

def temperature(request):
   #zip=requests.form['zip']ss
   r=requests.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22')
   json_object=r.json()
   my_dict1={'temp_k' :json_object['main']['temp']}
   return render(request,'mywebapp/index.html', context=my_dict1)
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles%}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hey</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "cs/style.css" %}/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the Header</h1>
    <img src="{% static "images/youownme.jpeg" %}" atl="Uh Oh">
    <h2> Temperature:{{temp_k}}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are some things wrong with your quotations, check the syntax highlighting.

Comment: You talking about html or views?

Comment: @RajorishiBhattacherajee: html.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you specify which part to focus on? Also am only facing the trouble in h2 block. The webpage is not displaying the value of temp_k.

Comment: @RajorshiBhattacharjee When you use `print(my_dict1)` in your view, is the correct data present for the key `temp_k`?

Comment: Yes, I verified it it by running the views. Its showing proper output.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works fine so you may want to check if you are rendering the right HTML files maybe, i've changed your code to make sure it's working and it is

```
my_dict1={'temp_k' :json_object['wind']['speed']}
```

sorry but I cant write a comment yet!

Comment: Am rendering the actual one, I say so because whenever am trying to render my_dict, it works. Talking about this part.

def hello(request):
   my_dict = {'insert_me': "From andu.py"}
   return render(request, 'mywebapp/index.html', context=my_dict)

Comment: @RajorshiBhattacharjee all what I've done is copying your codes I haven't added anything!

Comment: When i requested the same using the hello function it worked fine.
But not able to do it with temperature function. Please help me with this.

Comment: @RajorshiBhattacharjee can you add your views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `render` like this :

```
return render(request,'mywebapp/index.html',{'context':my_dict})
```